# 14.04 Software Updater says Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection

Tags: 14.04, package-management, update-manager

Hi I'm very new to linux and recently got Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to upgrade to 16.04 (and then hopefully 17.04)!

On opening the Software Updater and after it searches for updates, I get an error saying

```
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.
```

so I click settings and go from Main Server to Other server and select the best server. My server is now in Turkey:

```
ftp.linux.org.tr
```

I hit close and get a pop-up telling me my software is out of date and reminding me I need an internet connection to reload the updates. I have an internet connection so I click Reload and it updates the cache for a while and then I get the same Check Your Internet Connection error with the following details:

```
W:GPG error: https://repo.skype.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've done this several times with different servers and a few times I actually get the option to upgrade to 16.04 but when I click Upgrade I get that message again!! Please help!

I only recently got 14.04 so don't really care about any files or downloads, willing to delete them or reset the system but am not sure how? Any insight is appreciated!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is two-fold, because you have two problems.

---

#### Problem #1: You do not have the PGP key stored for the Skype repository.

There are [multiple ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) to fix this, but you can probably fix that issue with this one-liner:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

---

#### Problem #2: You are trying to use a PPA that doesn't publish Trusty 32-bit packages - the Nemo 3 PPA from WebUpd8 Team.

This is resolved by removing the nemo3 PPA from Webupd8 from your system.  Most likely, the PPA has its own entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that you can remove.  Otherwise you'll have to find and remove the entries for that PPA from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

---

Resolve both problems, and you will no longer get the software updater issue.